# OSGi in Eclipse cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, osgi

I'm working on an OSGi/Equinox plugin and cannot seem to get the Hibernate dependencies working.  I've added the Hibernate dependencies to my POM with Eclipse and it has successfully downloaded them.

[image]

However, I simply cannot use them in any project classes - as if they have not even been added as dependencies.

[image]

Why can I not simply add Hibernate as a dependency and then use it in my code?  **What's missing?**

I know this should be really straight forward and I assume I'm missing something somewhere.  A little pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)? If so, you need to add the package `org.hibernate.cfg` (and probably others) to the imported packages for your bundle (go to the Dependencies tab of the manifest editor).

PDE's approach is to only allow your code to see packages that you have explicitly imported **first**. Other tools such as [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) allow your code to see all packages on the build path, and subsequently generate the OSGi `Import-Package` statement based on what you actually used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No org.hibernate packages show up under Imported Packages in PDE and show errors when added manually, so I'm guessing I need to create a wrap of Hibernate using BND first?

Comment: Neil, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I needed to use BndTools in the end to create the Hibernate bundle. Quite a steep learning curve though and I'm still have some Hibernate-related exceptions (i.e. ClassNotFoundException for my domain classes)  though I'm much closer to the goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After adding to your pom you build it as mavne project or eclipse project?
I mean build first as;

## mvn clean install

Then create a eclipse project

## mvn eclipse:eclipse -o

Then import that to workspace ..You will be able to use the libraries

Comment: I'm using Eclipse not Maven directly, it does need to be an Eclipse Plugin Project as well. Maven isn't having any trouble finding and downloading the dependencies, the plugin however cannot seem to resolve them in any source file.